# Warning : file_put_contents() failed to open stream : No such file or directory

Tags: php

I am trying to upload an image from android to mysql

Now the path can be successfully uploaded but there's something wrong on this code

```
<?php

require_once '../database/database.php';

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    // base_64 encoded string from android
    $imageData = $_POST['image'];
    // edittext from android
    // $imageName = $_POST['image_name'];

    $path = "images/Sample.jpg";
    $actualPath = "http://192.168.254.123/*****/admin/$path";

    if($user->UploadFiles($actualPath))
    {
        file_put_contents($path, base64_decode($imageData));
        echo "Success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Failed";
    }
}

?>
```

On the line where `file_put_content` is the error . here's the full error

> Warning file_put_contents(images/Sample.jpg):failed to open stream:No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\projectname\admin\apk_api\upload_profile.php on line 17

Here's the proof that I can actually save the path on my database

[image]

and here's my directory

[image]
Can someone please help me out.

Comment: Check that the `images/` directory exists, it will not be created automatically.

Comment: Side note: Storing full paths isn't a good idea and isn't transferable from one platform/server to another.

Comment: it does exist @Progman I'll show you my directories

Comment: Noted sir , but for now I just wanted to work the app right now. @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: @Gin09 Which PHP script is called from the client?

Comment: If everything does exist, then check for permissions. Also, handling files usually means to use the `$_FILES` superglobal instead of `$_POST` along with a POST method and a valid enctype in the form.

Comment: @Progman the upload_profile.php which is the code is in my question sir

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner if permission is the problem the error should be : permission denied something right sir?

Comment: Should I post my android code also on my question???

Comment: You would be right about that. Echo the `$actualPath` variable and you'll see what everything resolves to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory `images/` does not exists from the point of view, where the `admin\apk_api\upload_profile.php` file is. The resulting directory path will be

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\projectname\admin\apk_api\images\
```

However, the target directory should be

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\projectname\admin\images\
```

Create a relative path based from the location of the `admin\apk_api\upload_profile.php` file. You have to use something like `../images/` to get to the target directory.